# How can I use replacement rules with randomized values?

Tags: random, rule

Suppose I have a list that I want to use replacement rules to replace each occurrence of a a given symbol with a randomly selected value, with this choice being randomized for each occurrence.

For a simple example, suppose `list={x,x,x,x}` and I want to replace each occurrence of `x` with a (potentially different) random integer between 1 and 5`. Defining

```
    rule=x->RandomInteger[5]
```

and evaluating `list/.rule` instead replaces all the instances of `x` with the **same** randomly chosen value. For example, returning `{5,5,5,5}` instead of `{2,3,3,5}`.

How can I obtain the properly randomized replacements?

Answer (score 6):

The issue with defining `rule = x -> RandomInteger[5]` and evaluating it is that Mathematica evaluates this `RandomInteger` at the time of definition, simply storing `rule = x -> 5` or similar. This in turn causes `list /. rule` to replace all of the `x` with the same value.

Instead, we need to delay this random choice so that it occurs *after* it has replaced each `x`.

A solution is to use `:>` ([`RuleDelayed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RuleDelayed.html)) instead of `->` (`Rule`), which holds the RHS unevaluated until the rule is used. This syntactic distinction is similar to that of `=` (`Set`) vs `:=` (`SetDelayed`):

```
   delayRule = x :> RandomInteger[5];
   list /. delayRule
   (* {2, 3, 1, 4} *)
```

An alternative solution is to use `Hold` and `ReleaseHold` to obtain the desired behavior:

```
randomRule = x -> Hold[RandomInteger[5]];

list /. randomRule
(* {Hold[RandomInteger[5]], ...., Hold[RandomInteger[5]]}*))

% // ReleaseHold
(* {4, 2, 3, 2} *)
```

Observe how using `Hold` in our rule replaces each `x` with a separate copy of `Hold[RandomInteger[5]]`. We then `ReleaseHold` to have the kernel evaluate each copy, giving our separately evaluated random choices.

Answer (score 5):

You want [`RuleDelayed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RuleDelayed.html) instead of `Rule` so the right hand side of the rule is recalculated every time the replacement rule is applied:

```
rule = x:> RandomInteger[5];
{x, 10, 10, x, 10} /. rule

(* Out: {3, 10, 10, 5, 10} *)
```